# division value coming wrong while dividing with some number to get percentage of a number in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get the percentage of 255. 255 is 100%. If I have numbered between 1- 255 I need to find out the percentage of that number.

i tried this formula but I'm getting values after decimal , how to remove decimal values .

```
int Battery_Dec = Convert.ToInt32(BatteryByte, 16);//12
double BatteryPercentage = Convert.ToDouble(Battery_Dec)/  255;//0
double Battery = BatteryPercentage * 100;
```

Comment: Well, what do you believe the value of the expression `Battery_Dec / 255` will be, bearing in mind that it's performing *integer* arithmetic?

Comment: (Hint: if you do the multiplication before the division, you can do this without any floating point arithmetic, assuming the value really is in the range 0-255. You should also learn about C# naming conventions.)

Comment: Yes, you are getting 0 always because you try to divide integer value to integer value where first integer is smaller second. Try to use float, double or decimal instead of integer

Comment: You should get a C# book and you'll find your answer in the first pages of chapter 1!

Answer (score 0):

If 1 == 0% and 255 == 100% then f(n)=(n-min)/(max-min), so in other words:

```
private static double ToPercent(int dec)
{    
     const int min = 1;
     const int max = 255;
     const double diff = max-min;
     return (dec-min)/diff * 100;
}
```